# Migrating all branches of GitHub repo to new location sends just Master as each origin/<branch>

Tags: macos, git, unix, github

I was very excited to get multiple repos migrated, but then come to find out my branches are all of master. Any thoughts on my mistake? Here is my process to migrating, specifically from a GHE to a GH account.

```
git clone <GHE repository>
cd <repository name>
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v '\->'`; do git branch --track $remote; done

git remote set-url origin <public GH repository>.git

git push -u --all origin
```

I am obviously attempting to track and migrate all branches, and if I am asking too much we can do one at a time if this is an issue fixing.

Attempting to simplify the steps, I used...

```
git push --all origin
```

and...

```
git push --mirror origin
```

With only master pushing to GitHub. `--mirror` did actually clean up the bad branches that duplicated master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigation with the team, this looks to be a clean migration process if all agree...

```
git clone <orig repository>
cd <repository name>
for i in `git branch -a | grep remote`; do git branch --track ${i#remotes/origin/} $i; done
```

3) Change your local copies origin to new location

```
git remote set-url origin <new repository>
```

4) Push it to new repository (as mirror of old)

```
git push --mirror
```

Before I accept, I would consider modifications and a better practice if exists.